# Why is this bivariate norm-function not differentiable in (0,1)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Why is this function not differentiable in (x,y) = (0,1) (According to my course material)?:

$\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}$

I see that this resembles a norm function.

I know that $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable in 0, because the function there is not smooth, but kinky. The reason is of course that function is the mirrored imaged on the negative domain of the postive domain.

In my multivariate function, I would expect that the function is not differentiable in (0,-1), because because of the (y+1) term in the argument, this is the translated version of:

$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

I am very confused about this, some feedback would be incrediably helpfull!

Kind regards

Comment: $(0, 1)$ or $(0, -1)$?

Comment: My course material says (0,1), but I would expect (0,-1) based on the principles of translation. But since the course material is quite rigourous, I think I made an error

Comment: Have you tried to compute the differential? It's actually differentiable in (0,1) but not in (0,-1).

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, compute the partial derivatives and observe that they are continuous in $(0, 1)$ ($\implies$ differentiability). So the error is in your course material

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!